Py4J security error while using pyspark ML library functions in azure databricks
I am trying to run the following code in my azure databricks workbook
import pyspark.ml.feature
from pyspark.ml.feature import Tokenizer,StopWordsRemover
tokenizer = Tokenizer()

However I am facing this error:
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling 
None.org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer. Trace:
py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Constructor public 
org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer(java.lang.String) is not 
whitelisted.

Similar errors are coming up for StopWordsRemover and some other functions from pyspark.ml.feature too
Is there a work around to avoid this error so that I can use the same code?

from pyspark.ml.feature import RegexTokenizer, StopWordsRemover
tokenizer = RegexTokenizer()
can you try the above?

Can you please share an image of your cluster configuration?

This error occurs with certain library methods when using a High Concurrency cluster with credential passthrough enabled.
If this is your situation, one potential workaround is to use a different cluster mode.
As per the py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: … is not whitelisted

This exception is thrown when you have accessed a method that Azure Databricks has not explicitly marked as safe for Azure Data Lake Storage credential passthrough clusters. In most cases, this means that the method could allow a user on a Azure Data Lake Storage credential passthrough cluster to access another user’s credentials.

Refernce: SO link.
